# How good is an optimal design (DOE)?

Tags: r, optimization, experiment-design

I am looking at an experiment with 5 factors (4 numeric and one nominal) with three levels for each numeric and 2 levels for the nominal. Instead of the 162 runs, I am interested in a small design (30 runs) using a specific postulated model for the response surface. Using the `AlgDesign` library in R I am able to generate these 30 design points:

```
library(AlgDesign)

candidates <- gen.factorial(levels = c(3,3,3,3,2),
                    #code all as numeric,  even factors so can do interactions
                      factors = NULL,
                    varNames = c("intro","duration","goto","fee","color")
                    )
candidates

desD <- optFederov(frml = ~intro+goto+duration+fee+color
                 + I(intro*intro)
                 +I(goto*goto)
                 +I(duration*duration)
                 +I(fee*fee)
                 + I(intro*goto)
                 + I(intro*duration)
                 + I(intro*fee)
                 + I(intro*color)
                 + I(goto*duration)
                 + I(goto*fee)
                 + I(goto*color)
                 + I(duration*fee)
                 + I(duration*color)
                 + I(fee*color),
                data = candidates,
                nTrials=30,
                criterion = "D",
                maxIteration = 1000, 
                eval=TRUE,
                nRepeats = 10)
```

Great, so now how good is this? The D criteria is

```
> desD$D
[1] 0.5422988
```

**Question #1: Is there a rule of thumb for if this is "acceptable"?**

The library allows one to run the design through an evaluation.

```
eval.design(frml = ~intro+goto+duration+fee+color
            + I(intro*intro)
            +I(goto*goto)
            +I(duration*duration)
            +I(fee*fee)
            + I(intro*goto)
            + I(intro*duration)
            + I(intro*fee)
            + I(intro*color)
            + I(goto*duration)
            + I(goto*fee)
            + I(goto*color)
            + I(duration*fee)
            + I(duration*color)
            + I(fee*color),design = desD$design,confounding = TRUE,X = candidates)
```

Which produces

```
$confounding
                          [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]   [,10]   [,11]
(Intercept)            -1.0000 -0.0898  0.0726 -0.4094  0.0383 -0.3290  0.7405  0.7806  0.7324  0.7541  0.2098
intro                  -0.0062 -1.0000  0.0842  0.0805 -0.0332  0.0354 -0.0087 -0.0645  0.0805 -0.0050  0.0038
goto                    0.0049  0.0810 -1.0000  0.0060  0.0130 -0.0041 -0.0118  0.0066 -0.0063  0.0001 -0.0849
duration               -0.0278  0.0787  0.0061 -1.0000 -0.0250  0.0203  0.0770  0.0297 -0.0185 -0.0076  0.0246
fee                     0.0025 -0.0311  0.0126 -0.0239 -1.0000 -0.0125  0.0084 -0.0262  0.0077  0.0004  0.0568
color                  -0.0177  0.0273 -0.0033  0.0161 -0.0103 -1.0000 -0.0020  0.0258 -0.0001  0.0031  0.0097
I(intro * intro)        0.3066 -0.0517 -0.0728  0.4690  0.0536 -0.0151 -1.0000 -0.0058  0.0647  0.0602  0.0813
I(goto * goto)          0.2605 -0.3092  0.0330  0.1456 -0.1339  0.1602 -0.0047 -1.0000  0.0265  0.0040  0.0549
I(duration * duration)  0.2905  0.4590 -0.0373 -0.1078  0.0471 -0.0007  0.0620  0.0315 -1.0000  0.0339 -0.1652
I(fee * fee)            0.2847 -0.0271  0.0005 -0.0423  0.0026  0.0217  0.0549  0.0045  0.0323 -1.0000 -0.1389
I(intro * goto)         0.0169  0.0044 -0.1024  0.0292  0.0703  0.0145  0.0159  0.0133 -0.0336 -0.0297 -1.0000
I(intro * duration)     0.0091  0.0349  0.0368  0.0470 -0.1013  0.0590  0.0002  0.0080  0.0105 -0.0379  0.0443
I(intro * fee)          0.0189  0.0570  0.0485 -0.1040 -0.0341  0.0382  0.0154 -0.0077 -0.0630 -0.0096 -0.0486
I(intro * color)        0.0034 -0.2138  0.0249  0.0622  0.0264 -0.0187  0.0119 -0.0429  0.0152  0.0019 -0.0801
I(goto * duration)     -0.0004  0.0445  0.0078 -0.0399 -0.0384 -0.0062  0.0505 -0.0012 -0.0039 -0.0493  0.0320
I(goto * fee)          -0.0003  0.0332 -0.0133 -0.0099 -0.0060  0.0044 -0.0462  0.0064  0.0496 -0.0052 -0.0274
I(goto * color)         0.0259  0.0300 -0.1740  0.0400  0.0035 -0.0015 -0.0885  0.0056  0.0061  0.0042  0.0055
I(duration * fee)      -0.0054 -0.0940 -0.0304  0.0287 -0.0454  0.0472  0.0381 -0.0191  0.0003 -0.0130 -0.0549
I(duration * color)    -0.0016  0.0501 -0.0085 -0.1986  0.0270 -0.0226  0.0242 -0.0199 -0.0049  0.0047 -0.0344
I(fee * color)         -0.0033  0.0341  0.0013  0.0257 -0.1876  0.0169 -0.0100  0.0256 -0.0033 -0.0013  0.0476
                         [,12]   [,13]   [,14]   [,15]   [,16]   [,17]   [,18]   [,19]   [,20]
(Intercept)             0.1190  0.2467  0.0508 -0.0053 -0.0038  0.3719 -0.0706 -0.0239 -0.0508
intro                   0.0318  0.0518 -0.2232  0.0389  0.0290  0.0300 -0.0859  0.0536  0.0367
goto                    0.0322  0.0425  0.0250  0.0066 -0.0112 -0.1672 -0.0267 -0.0088  0.0013
duration                0.0418 -0.0925  0.0635 -0.0341 -0.0085  0.0391  0.0256 -0.2079  0.0271
fee                    -0.0865 -0.0291  0.0259 -0.0314 -0.0049  0.0033 -0.0389  0.0271 -0.1893
color                   0.0415  0.0269 -0.0151 -0.0042  0.0030 -0.0011  0.0333 -0.0187  0.0141
I(intro * intro)        0.0009  0.0831  0.0741  0.2624 -0.2401 -0.5263  0.2069  0.1540 -0.0642
I(goto * goto)          0.0350 -0.0334 -0.2150 -0.0049  0.0269  0.0270 -0.0838 -0.1023  0.1324
I(duration * duration)  0.0543 -0.3265  0.0902 -0.0192  0.2471  0.0349  0.0013 -0.0298 -0.0205
I(fee * fee)           -0.1875 -0.0474  0.0107 -0.2338 -0.0245  0.0230 -0.0643  0.0276 -0.0074
I(intro * goto)         0.0468 -0.0512 -0.0970  0.0324 -0.0278  0.0063 -0.0582 -0.0427  0.0595
I(intro * duration)    -1.0000  0.0108  0.0672  0.0370 -0.0563 -0.0412 -0.0954  0.0589 -0.0214
I(intro * fee)          0.0108 -1.0000 -0.0388 -0.0566  0.0585  0.0647  0.0000 -0.0220  0.0418
I(intro * color)        0.0587 -0.0338 -1.0000 -0.0307  0.0495  0.0947 -0.0176  0.0419 -0.0098
I(goto * duration)      0.0385 -0.0590 -0.0367 -1.0000 -0.0296  0.0317  0.0420 -0.0029  0.0393
I(goto * fee)          -0.0586  0.0609  0.0591 -0.0296 -1.0000 -0.0335 -0.0375  0.0442  0.0025
I(goto * color)        -0.0376  0.0589  0.0989  0.0278 -0.0293 -1.0000  0.0519  0.0125 -0.0087
I(duration * fee)      -0.0951  0.0000 -0.0201  0.0401 -0.0359  0.0568 -1.0000 -0.0309  0.0414
I(duration * color)     0.0501 -0.0187  0.0408 -0.0023  0.0361  0.0117 -0.0264 -1.0000 -0.0170
I(fee * color)         -0.0181  0.0353 -0.0095  0.0319  0.0020 -0.0080  0.0351 -0.0169 -1.0000

$determinant
[1] 0.5422988

$A
[1] 3.51777

$I
[1] 20.58251

$Geff
[1] 0.696

$Deffbound
[1] 0.646

$diagonality
[1] 0.782

$gmean.variances
[1] 1.966862
```

Question #2: From one of the package vignettes , this is a statement made about the design they were observing and the eval function. **Does one look then at these things only from a relative perspective (unlike fractional factorials where effects are either clear or confounded) where diagonality of 0.78 is pretty good (since 1 is perfect) and if there are entries in the confounding matrix that are "large" then we consider the effects as problematic to clearly estimate them?**

[image]

**EDIT: 1**

Here is one thought I had - perhaps someone could give their thoughts if this approach is valid to make sure the effects are somewhat non-confounded.

Create dummy response data, fit the model of interest and then check VIF. Here, none are above 2 so we feel good about being able to get good clear 
estimates of the effects.

```
    #dummy response
    y <- rbinom(nrow(desD$design),size = 12000,prob = 0.009)
    non_response<-12000-y

    mod <- glm(cbind(y,non_response)~intro+goto+duration+fee+color
             + I(intro*intro)
             +I(goto*goto)
             +I(duration*duration)
             +I(fee*fee)
             + I(intro*goto)
             + I(intro*duration)
             + I(intro*fee)
             + I(intro*color)
             + I(goto*duration)
             + I(goto*fee)
             + I(goto*color)
             + I(duration*fee)
             + I(duration*color)
             + I(fee*color), data=desD$design, family = "binomial")

    library(car)

    car::vif(mod)

                 intro                   goto               duration                    fee                  color 
              1.045220               1.066770               1.095618               1.159182               1.083592 
      I(intro * intro)         I(goto * goto) I(duration * duration)           I(fee * fee)        I(intro * goto) 
              1.136307               1.225223               1.238652               1.104796               1.053494 
   I(intro * duration)         I(intro * fee)       I(intro * color)     I(goto * duration)          I(goto * fee) 
              1.061060               1.038913               1.144018               1.058265               1.044455 
       I(goto * color)      I(duration * fee)    I(duration * color)         I(fee * color) 
              1.050094               1.063997               1.066333               1.100737
```

Comment: I have always thought of "optimal" as either true or false.  This comes from "control system engineering" first and "doe" second.  In DOE you can constrain your domain to integer values or such, so that extremizing the measure of goodness is not as extremal if continuous values were allowed, but still it qualifies as optimal.  Personally, I would not like d-optimal that wasn't actually **d**-optimal or optimal.

Comment: There is more than one criteria for optimal design.  In the realm of DOE we also have the concept of robust design that Taguchi introduced.  People like George Box and Jeff Wu followed up on refining it.  Maybe you should look at Jeff's book.

Comment: A URL for Jeff's book :www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471699462.html .

Comment: A book URL is helpful but what would really be nice is if someone could give an explanation of how to interpret the confounding matrix and diagonality that the algdesign package provides to help understand how good a particular design is..

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question (except that comparing to other designs is one way to understand the quality), but here's a design that seems to do better for the 2nd order factors. [63, 35, 138, 151, 27, 15, 43, 133, 109, 90, 80, 32, 2, 132, 39, 31, 85, 76, 141, 19, 48, 69, 122, 98, 65, 126, 101, 145, 13, 158]

Comment: On what basis do you think it better?

Comment: Based on JMP-reported power analysis values (estimating parameters as 1) and better fraction of design space plots.

Comment: How does JMP go about / what tools does it provide to take an optimal design and determine its goodness (including level of confounding in the effects you are interested in)? Might that be an answer to my question?

Comment: What is your sample size constraint?  Is it $30$?  Or can you go higher?  And what is the purpose of your analysis?  Hypothesis test?  Effect estimates?  How accurate do you want your conclusion to be?

Comment: This is an example case. But the constraint would be around number of runs. This is an experiment to be analyzed with logistic regression. The effect estimates and a predictive model would be the normal outcomes. The example is from this paper - which mirrors exactly my purpose. www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/196-31.pdf

Comment: Generally I am researching how to tell if an optimal design like this is "good". With a fractional factorial we can see which effects are clear and which are confounded. I am trying to research how to evaluate this type of design in a similar way.

Comment: First you must define what "good" means to you, operationally.  Then simulate data many times from the model, using your design, evaluate your criteria, and look at a histogram of criterion values.  Then you can tell if this design is "good"  for you!

Comment: There's no rule of thumb that applies to all experiments.  Like, if you're working at CERN looking for the Higgs boson, you'll want astronomical amounts of data before even considering a result to be potentially valid; you can't just walk in there and tell them that 30 points, or 162, are enough - that's silly.  So, if you're looking for some set approach to profiling a physical system's response in a limited set of evaluations, presumably you'll want to have some prior knowledge of that system and a reason to believe that it's sufficiently well-behaved.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen can you elaborate this into an answer? I think there are established ways of knowing how good the design is - Algdesign appears to offer a couple methods, I am just not sure about the interpretation. Further, I put forward a thought on using VIF to see if the effects, once estimated, would be highly confounded. Again, just not sure if this is a good method.

Comment: In response to how does JMP evaluate and compare designs, it's not my area of expertise, but here are links to the JMP doc: [Evaluate Designs](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/13/Evaluate_Designs.shtml), [Compare Designs](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/13/Compare_Designs.shtml) (Btw, as asker of the question you get notified of all comments. In order for others to be notified, you need to tag them with '@' as in @B_Miner.)

Comment: @xan, the alias matrix description is exactly what I was "hoping" the confounding matrix from Algdesign showed - but it is not a clear how to interpret it.